# A sequence for which there is $k$ such that for each $\epsilon >0$ we have that $|x_n -l | < \epsilon$ for all $n \geq k$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$. For each $\epsilon >0$ we have that $|x_n -l | < \epsilon$ for all $n \geq k$, where $k$ is **NOT** dependent on $\epsilon$. What do we know about $(x_n)$?

---

**Progress**. The definition of a convergent sequence is exactly the same as above, except that $k$ is dependent on $\epsilon$. Can we then say that, instead of the sequence only converging to $l$, that the sequence is  the constant sequence $(x_n) = (l)$ when $n \geq k$?

Comment: How does what you have written compare to the definition of a convergent sequence?

Comment: If $k$ is constant then you know $x_n$ for $n \ge k$

Comment: @graydad - the definition of a convergent sequence is exactly the same, except that $k$ is dependent on $\epsilon$. Can we then say that, instead of the sequence only converging to $l$, that the sequence is  the constant sequence $(x_n) = (l)$ when $n \geq k$?

Comment: @user229672 If the inequality holds for all $k$, I would agree!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you cannot say that the sequence is constant. The sequence $(10, 100, ..., 10^{10^{10}} , 1, 1, 1, ... )$ is also a sequence that satisfies your premise. But you can prove that the sequence is "eventually" constant - constant beyond a point.

The given hypothesis is that there is a natural number $k$ such that for each $\epsilon \gt 0$ and for each $n \ge k$ $|x_n - l| \lt \epsilon$. Suppose the sequence is not eventually constant. Then for any natural number $n$ there is another $n' \gt n$ such that $x_{n'} \neq x_n$. Taking $k = n$ and noting that $l$ by definition is equal to $x_k$ you may arrive at a contradiction by picking $\epsilon = |x_k - x_{k'}|$.

Answer (score 2):

Pick some $n \geq k$. Then, since $k$ does not depend on $\varepsilon$, you have $|x_n-l|<\varepsilon$ for every $\varepsilon$. Now take $\varepsilon \to 0$ to reach the conclusion.

Comment: Hence $(x_n) = (l)$ whenever $n \geq k$?

Comment: Yes, that's the conclusion.